# ERROR en build de next js

Tags: javascript, nextjs, build, next

tengo este componente de panel de administrador que una vez q el usuario se loguea te redirige automaticamente al panel con la lista de productos el problema es que al hacer el build el componente productTable da un error si quito el componente el build corre perfecto
productTable hace un fetch para obtener todos los productos supongo que el error se da por que trata de renderizar algo q todavia no tiene alguna idea de como lo puedo solucionar?

```
import ProductTable from "@/components/admin/ProductTable";
import Link from "next/link";
import React from "react";

const Admin = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="w-full flex items-center pr-1 ">
        <h1 className="w-full h-12 flex justify-start pl-10 items-center text-2xl text-zinc-900 uppercase font-extrabold italic">
          Panel Administrador
        </h1>
        <Link href={"/admin/create"}>
          <button className="w-24 p-2 h-8 bg-orange-500 rounded-xl text-sm  flex items-center justify-center text-white mt-10 mr-200">
            <p>Crear nuevo</p>
          </button>
        </Link>
      </div>
      <ProductTable />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Admin;
```

Comment: y el error cual es?